auth not working as expected when provided with initializeServerApp
I'm following Firebase + NextJS guide.
Looking a this code, https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-web/blob/master/nextjs-end/src/lib/firebase/serverApp.js
// enforces that this code can only be called on the server
// https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#keeping-server-only-code-out-of-the-client-environment
import "server-only";

import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { initializeServerApp } from "firebase/app";

import { firebaseConfig } from "./config";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

export async function getAuthenticatedAppForUser() {
  const idToken = headers().get("Authorization")?.split("Bearer ")[1];

  const firebaseServerApp = initializeServerApp(
    firebaseConfig,
    idToken
      ? {
          authIdToken: idToken,
        }
      : {}
  );

  const auth = getAuth(firebaseServerApp);
  await auth.authStateReady();

  return { firebaseServerApp, currentUser: auth.currentUser };
}

The first time I call this function with newly signed in user, I always get undefined user. But, on from the second call, I get the correct current User. My suspicion is on auth not yet being initialized but then what's the point of auth.authStateReady()? When I initialize app with regular initializeApp on the client, I wait readiness on the auth and it works as intended.
I'm trying to use this to validate currently signed in user. Is this recommended? Thanks.
EDIT: One thing I've found out while debugging, it does seem like this is a timing issue because a simple breakpoint is enough time delay for auth to be populated with valid data. I'm just frustrated that authStateReady returns done even if auth should have been invoked.

Would you be able to share a minimal reproducible example so that we can see where you are printing user or is this issue replicable in the repository you shared as well?

@Dharmaraj hey! You can simply clone that repo (link above) and add print statements. Anyhow, the logs are showing "undefined" for auth.currentUser. The print happens after await auth.authStateReady()
